# AMS Publish livestream and liveevent at the same time

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-media-server, http-live-streaming

I am currently working on a new Version of a customers Webcam Application. Currently it just connects to a single AMS Application and works fine as expected. 
Now we want to realize a mobile Stream as well. Finally I got it to work but just by streaming directly from the Flash Media Live Encoder (connecting directly to the livepkgr Application on the AMS).

So for the main Application I have to find a solution, where the Stream connects to the default Application (for desktop Clients) and a second Connection to the livepkgr Application which will create HLS specific Video chunks.

I am not sure if I get it right, that we have to use the livepkgr for HLS Streaming by itself. Maybe it is possible to extend the current Application (let´s call it "camchatdev") to provide HLS ready chunks as well.

Maybe some can help me out? I dont know where to start.

here are the current connects:

1. Camchat Desktop clients: rtmp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80/appname
2. Camchat Mobile clients (via FMLE): rtmp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:80/livepkgr/livestream1?adbe-live-event=myliveevent

To put it in a nutshell: I want to have the second Connection be made automatically when the first one is established. Other solution would be that the first connection (or application) will automatically create HLS ready chunks.

Hope you understand my need ;-)

Best,
Patrick

Comment: You should be able to have a single application do everything if you have the pro version.   What version of AMS are you running?

Comment: Sorry for my late response - We are currently using AMS Professional 5.0.6 r6102 - Do you have an indication where I have to start? Any Keyword or Documentation in that concern? Thanks

Comment: Every documentation I found references to the livepkr Application. As I understand it correctly, a single Application can be configured to publish HLS Ready Streams as well. Do I only have to take the Application.xml / Events.xml to establish this feature?

Comment: Little Update: I wrote an onPublish Method in my Main.asc (of my application), where another second connection to the livepkgr Application is established. It works fine, as I can see some traces on the livepkgr Application side. But when I open the HLS Stream in Safari, I just got a Player without any Images / Videos. If I connect the same way over Flash Media Encoder, it works like a charm. What am I missing here? (Code Main.asc: http://pastebin.com/wHdQmZAJ )

Comment: Traces of livepkgr: http://pastebin.com/FtTjLtnU (With connecting from my main.asc)
Traces of livepkgr: http://pastebin.com/HnXAZEZe (With Adobe Media Live Encoder - Which is working as expected)

Comment: I was able to solve this problem. Please refer to https://forums.adobe.com/message/7558925